# Parsing a string with Dimensions in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing, text-files

I have a string which contains some values as a set.Now as per my requirement i have to parse this string into sets.Here is my string Contents..

```
14/01/13 09:06AM   502 19 <I>01203851288            0'00 00:00'45            D0
```

Now i have to parse this string as:

```
Date:         14/01/13
Time:         09:06AM
Extension:    502
line:         19
Number:       <I>01203851288
Ring:         0'00
Span:         00:00'45
CD:           D0
```

So my question is how can i parse the given string into resultant.Can i use substring concept to split the given string...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Dimensions.

Comment: Your parsing strategy should depend on the data format.  Is it fixed length fields?  Delimited?  Something else?

Comment: I assume fixed length. If the length of the fields remains the same or do not exceed a maximum length. Yes you can.

Comment: @Dan-o i wanted to say about substring..Here in the given string is there any universal logic to split into resultant

Comment: The easy way would be 'text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);'.

Comment: There is no universal parser.  Parsers know about a data format.  If your data format is not what the parser knows about it won't work properly.

Comment: @wonko79: there's not enough data here to make that recommendation.  For instance you have not determined if there are escape characters - like what happens when a field contains a legitimate space.

Comment: @wonko79 How to apply text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) in the current scenario ..Data formate would be same always.Whenever an empty space comes it should add that subtsring into next field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string str = "14/01/13 09:06AM   502 19 <I>01203851288            0'00 00:00'45            D0";
        var strings = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.one doubt how to add this string into Date,extension etc

Comment: I am not sure what Date/Time/Extension are. If they are the properties in a class then you can assign the value to them separately. The string array "strings" in the answer contains each part of the string, which means strings[0] = "14/01/13", strings[1] ="09:06AM",etc. if Date is a DateTime-typed variable, you should use DateTime.Parse(string) to convert string to a datetime. So are the others. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I mean how can i split the values present in var strings